# How to crop a video in Kdenlive

Tags: video, kdenlive

Is there a way to crop a video in Kdenlive in this way:

1. select a crop region.
2. output a video in the size of the crop region.

It sounds like a common use case, e.g. record a screen and remove some irrelevant portions.

Popular search engines don't show a method in kdenlive that would let you output an arbitrary size of a video. You could select a crop region and manually copy (the window is modal) the size values into the project resolution setting and transform the clip to move it into the right place, but that's a really cumbersome way to do it.